# How do I convert an array to a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hashmap

I have an array and tried to convert the array contents to a hash with keys and values. Index 0 is a key, index 1 is a value, index 2 is a key, index 3 is a value, etc.

But it is not producing the expected result. The code is below:

```
open (FILE, "message.xml") || die "Cannot open\n";

$var = <FILE>;

while ($var ne "")
{
 chomp ($var);
 @temp = split (/[\s\t]\s*/,$var);
 push(@array,@temp);
 $var = <FILE>;
}

$i = 0;
$num = @array;
    while ($i < $num)
{
 if (($array[$i] =~ /^\w+/i) || ($array[$i] =~ /\d+/))
 {
#   print "Matched\n";
#   print "\t$array[$i]\n";
  push (@new, $array[$i]);
 }
 $i ++;
}
print "@new\n";


use Tie::IxHash;
tie %hash, "Tie::IxHash";

%hash = map {split ' ', $_, 2} @new;

while ((my $k, my $v) = each %hash)
{
 print "\t $k => $v\n";
}
```

The output produced is not correct:

```
name Protocol_discriminator attribute Mandatory type nibble value 7 min 0 max F name Security_header attribute Mandatory type nibble value 778 min 0X00 max 9940486857
         name => Security_header
         attribute => Mandatory
         type => nibble
         value => 778
         min => 0X00
         max => 9940486857
```

In the output you can see that the hash is formed only with one part, and another part of the array is not getting created in the hash.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 47):

Nothing more to it than:

```
%hash = @array;
```

Comment: Assuming the data in @array is stored as key, value, key, value, etc.

Comment: @Hawk and his voters: Please take your time to read the question. OP already states this in his/her question.

Comment: Thanks @Hawk, a very useful note for those of us who only read the title and immediately jump to the answers ;)

Comment: How to convert without extra variable? I try this %{ @_ }{ key }, but it does not work ((

Answer (score 38):

On a related note, to convert all elements of `@array` into keys of `%hash`. Some people ending up here might really want this instead...

This allows use of exists function:

```
my %hash;
$hash{$_}++ for (@array);
```

Comment: Or `%hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array;` (which differs from your solution in that elements that occur multiple times are set to 1).

Comment: @KeithThompson’s variation is functionally identical to `my %hash; $hash{$_} = 1 for (@array);`. Is one preferable to the other with respect to speed/resource consumption?

Answer (score 1):

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array
```