# Perl Array to Hash

Tags: perl, hash

I was taking inspiration from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/16157433/3880362. The only thing that it did not do was increment the value of each key as it was populated. I.e.

I have:

```
$Hash => {
      'Val1' => 1,
      'Val2' => 1,
      'Val3' => 1
 };
```

When I want

```
$Hash => {
      'Val1' => 0,
      'Val2' => 1,
      'Val3' => 2
 };
```

Code:

```
$Hash{$_}++ for (@line);
```

Comment: `$Hash{$_}=keys %Hash for (@line);`

Comment: What about using the index of the array as the value?  Something like this: `perl -MData::Dump -e '@line = qw(apple banana cherry tree); $hash{$line[$_]} = $_ for 0..$#line; END {dd \%hash}'
{ apple => 0, banana => 1, cherry => 2, tree => 3 }`.  Otherwise can maybe set up a counter variable, but not sure if you can do it without a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the other question, your input is `@array` and your output is `%hash` where the values of the hash are offset in the array of the hash's keys in the array.  If so, I think you want this:

```
$hash{$array[$_]} = $_ for (0 .. $#array);
```

Comment: Putting some keywords here, because this is a good answer.  This is like a value-to-index hash.  Good for doing something like a CSV header.

Comment: ie: `$value2idx{$values[$_]} = $_ for 0..$#values;` where what being iterated is the array index.   The first comment on the OP also does the same thing iterating the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array indices and use those to populate the hash values.  Perl arrays start at index `0`.  The last index of array `@foo` is `$#foo`.  So you can use the range operator `..` to get all of the indices as `0..$#foo`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys++;

my @letters = 'a'..'g';
my %hash = map { $letters[ $_ ] => $_ } 0..$#letters;

print Dumper(\%hash);
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 0,
          'b' => 1,
          'c' => 2,
          'd' => 3,
          'e' => 4,
          'f' => 5,
          'g' => 6
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to turn all elements of array `@line` into hash keys of hash `%hash` with hash values going from 0 on. In that case:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @line = qw( Val1 Val2 Val3 );
my %hash;

my $n = 0;
$hash{$_} = $n++ for(@line);

print Dumper(\%hash), "\n";
```

Note that `Dumper` will dump all the hash keys and their values, but not in the order they were created.